# Azure website rewrite rule

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a Wordpress-based web site hosted in Azure websites with a custom domain (www.mydomain.com) that is working great.

Now I want to let another domain  (www.anotherdomain.com) respond to the same Azure website. But www.anotherdomain.com is an old website where its pages are no longer available either in new or old places.

This means I need to redirect any URL from www.anotherdomain.com to the root (home page) of www.mydomain.com without any http error messages.

Example: www.anotherdomain.com/products/blablabla.aspx to www.mydomain.com

I suppose I have to add some rewrite rules on web.config, but I have no idea on how to make them.

In addition, what would be the changes (if any):
1 - At my DNS zones for both domains
2 - Azure website domain configuration.

Thank you,

Igor

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to assign hostname www.anotherexample.com to the same wordpress site that hosts www.example.com by following instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).

After that you will need to add a redirect rule to your site that will redirect requests www.anotherexample.com to www.example.com:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect host name" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.anotherexample.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hi. I suspect this is the way to go too. I managed to sucessfully add www.anotherdomain.com add at azure website domain configuration. Now I have both www.mydomain.com and www.anotherdomain.com. The DNS records seems to be OK. 
The only thing that seems to be broken is the redirect rule. I have tried some of them, including the one you suggest, but the result is the same. 
1 - The navigation on www.mydomain.com breaks (404 error everywhere)
2 - Redirect works ok when I navigate to www.anotherdomain.com
3 - Navigate to www.anotherdomain.com/something.php gives a 404 error after redirecting.

Comment: Where did you add this rule in relation to other rules in your web.config? It should be the very first rule in the <rules> collection.

Comment: Hello RuslanY. I managed to make it work, but I had to remove the {R:1} from the action declaration. Otherwise, if I browse to www.anotherdomain.com/abc.php I would be redirected to www.mydomain.com/abc.php and I need only www.mydomain.com.
After doing that, it seems to work now.

Comment: I am glad that you made it work. Yes, the intention of {R:1} was to preserve the URL path while redirecting. If that is not needed then it is correct to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If your new site is WordPress based so it will very easy for you. just go to DNS management zone and add entry of domain forwarding and off Path Forwarding.No need to do any change in Azure site settings.

if you will turn On Path Forwarding even then WordPress will handle and it will not give any http error.

for example my site is http://subhashsingh.com and from http://study-desk.org you can get the same site even you will hit a wrong url like http://study-desk.org/12/new .

Comment: What kind of DNS record type makes forwarding? What about path forwarding. What do you mean by turning it ON/OFF?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your consideration.Every Domain management panel having domain forwarding option. you need to set it to forward the requests to other domain. like got www.anotherdomain.com domain management panel ( if you have domain rights) and set it to

Comment: forward on www.mydomain.com and save your settings. it makes automatic change in A records according to the name server.

Comment: Path forwarding is nothing it just a forwarding type if you will enable path forwarding it will forward the domain with full path like www.xyz.com/12/hello.aspx will forward to www.abc.in/12/hello.aspx. if you will set it to forward only it will forward www.xyz.com/12/hello.aspx to www.abc.in

Comment: Hello subhash. As far as I know, the only DNS changes I can make at every domain I own is to add/edit/remove A,CNAME, TXT, SVR, etc domain records. I have not seem path forward configuration at domain management level.
Either way, it seems I found a solution on the previous answer.

Comment: Its great if your problem is solved. but as per my I knowledge domain forwarding is very popular feature and it depends on your domain registrar & provider. you can say basically its easy interface of rewrite rule